# How to remove primary key from strongly typed Dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

How can I remove primary key or foreign key from strongly typed data-set in designer view ? I tried followings without success,

- Change unique key attribute to false
- Delete dataset and add it again

I am getting duplicate values for ID so it's intended but how can I stop this annoying error ?

[image]

[image]

If i preview the data there is no nulls being returned so it's just duplicate value i think..

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have a stored procedure which joins and outerapply several tables, outcome is I am getting several records for same ID but other column information is different, because  in strongly typed dataset it was a primary key I was getting enable constraints error, so I managed to delete primary key and it worked, real problem was me not finding how to delete it but eventually found it

Comment: @Pete thanks for your help, I changed my approach for now, but i did understand it better with your explanation now, cheers :), i was getting unnecessary down votes, which is why i had to delete my question

Comment: @Pete as you answer is valid, please add it here and i will accept it, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212586/display-columns-stacked-vertically-in-a-single-tr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, right clicked on the column and then clicked on "Delete Key" for each column.