# Displaying 2 columns in a same row and another in 2nd row within a single tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I made,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A: $10</td>
    <td>B: $15</td>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t77remtc/1/

I want to add 3 `<td>` in a single `<tr>` tag in such a way that 2 `<td>` will be displayed on a single line and third `<td>` needs to go on 2nd line, condition is that they must need to be in same `<tr>`.

Sorry for any confusion earlier.

Comment: Still using IE8 - Refuse it

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/t77remtc/3/

Comment: Could you maybe explain why would you want such thing? that does not make sense?

Comment: Even most of use not use IE8 How can we check?

Comment: In chrome and in IE9 it's working fine. In both there is on same row.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t77remtc/4/ ?

Comment: @THE not sure but if you want the bottom one to look like the picture than use `colspan="2"`

Comment: @THE in chrome. http://i.stack.imgur.com/fPrrz.png and in IE: http://i.stack.imgur.com/t9a8K.png

Comment: You keep changing your question... I saw you also removed this post now you enabled it again with tweak question. Now I have 3 down vote... wow

Comment: @TomMarulak I clearly showed what I wanted in the picture, however my words  were confusing, I am sorry for that, I didn't changed my question but made it more clear, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table structure you should be able to achieve what you want by using the following styles.  The trick is to turn the table back into block elements and then style them.  Please note the nth child element of this is based on 2 columns - if you had three columns as in your second example, then it would be `3n+1`

```css
table, table * {
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
table {
    padding:3px 0 0 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:299px;
}
table:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:144px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    margin-right:3px;
    float:left; 
    
}
th:nth-child(2n + 1), td:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    clear:left;
}
.newline {
    float:none;
    width:291px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th colspan="2">Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td colspan="2">$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td colspan="2">$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A: $10</td>
        <td>B: $15</td>
        <td class="newline">Sum: $25</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please note I have added colspans to the above table to make your html valid for when css is disabled

Answer (score 1):

This is not IE8 bug, instead your markup is not correct.

You need to merge the column on top like this `<td colspan="1" rowspan="3"></td>`

```
   <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Sum: $25</td>
    </tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t77remtc/2/

new version: http://jsfiddle.net/t77remtc/13/